# Flutter Firebase Auth: Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I implemented authentication through Google in my project flutter. And it works fine, but some users report the following error when entering Error 403 Forbidden. For what is this?. Thank you
[image]

Comment: Sorry for being out of topic but are you releasing the app in the development environment? The red error screen should not show to the user. And it should only appear in debug.

It may be difficult for us to find a solution if you don't provide the code related to the authentication problem that occurred. But from the error, maybe you didn't handle it if the login failed. Because in the image there is an error 403, which means the authentication process failed.

Comment: @SeptianDika Correctly, what you see as a red screen is an alert for errors such as an incorrect password. This error returned a web code which is somewhat unexpected, which is why it filled the entire screen to show all that text.

Comment: It seems I found the error and this happens when they cancel the account selection window many times.